# How can I match the length of one variable to another in python?

Tags: python

I am currently developing this python code and I am trying to match the length of the user's surname to their name length.

If the user's surname is greater than their message, then the code will successfully subtract the excess characters in the user's name to make both variables equal.

However if the user's name is greater than their surname, the code should loop through the user's surname and add the required amount of characters to make both variables equal.

Comment: hasn't this been answered in your previous question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047824/how-to-evade-spaces-in-a-users-message-from-a-vigen%C3%A8re-cipher-keyword-in-pyth

Answer (score 0):

I use this function :

```
def pad(key, wanted_len):
    lk = len(key)
    if lk > wanted_len:
        return key[:wanted_len]
    else:
        bigerkey = key * ((wanted_len / lk) + 1)
        return bigerkey[:wanted_len]
```

The first part of the if is pretty straightforward: if the key is larger than you expect, just truncat it. Otherwize, use the operator `*` on key to repeat `n` times, where n is the expected siwe divised by the size of the key.

for example:

```
>>> print 'hello ' * 5
hello hello hello hello hello
```

A nice suggestion from horns simplifies the previous code:

```
def pad(key, wanted_len):
   return (key * ((wanted_len // len(key)) + 1))[:wanted_len]
```

Another possible (more pythonic) is to use `itertools.cycle`:

```
def pad(key, len):
    it = itertools.cycle(key)
    return ''.join([it.next() for _ in xrange(len)])
```

The iterator on the key will pop you out a letter in the order of the iterable provided (key here) at each `next()`, and cycle in the end of the itirable.

Comment: `return (key * ((wanted_len // lk) + 1))[:wanted_len]` should work, you don't need the if. Also, note that `//` for int division is required in python 3

Comment: Thanks but could you please explain you solution, i don't exactly understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import cycle
def combine(text, keyword):
    return ''.join(key for key, char in zip(cycle(keyword), text))
```

cylce makes an infinite generator over your keyword. for a keyword like 'abc' it will yield a, b, c, a, b, c, a, .... zip will stop after iterating over your text.

Stepwise explanation of the function:
zip (more information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for a, b in zip( [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b']):
    print (a, b)
#1 a
#2 b
# stops after 2 steps, because ['a', 'b'] has only two elements
```

cycle makes an infinite generator:

```
keyword = '12'
# cycle(keyword) -> 1 2 1 2 1 2 .... (infinite times)
text = 'abcde'
for key, char in zip(cycle(keyword), text):
    print (key, char)
# 1 a
# 2 b
# 1 c 
# 2 d
# 1 e
#stops (cause len(text) == 5)
keys = [key for key, char in zip(cycle(keyword), text)]
#keys == [ '1', '2', '1', '2', '1']
newkeyword = ''.join(keys)
#join joins a iterable of strings with '' as delimiter between them
#newkeyword == '12121'
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly what this function does. I am relatively new to python.